# Stripe/PHP: Handling Customer object succeeds but charging fails (4000000000000341)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

In Stripe, the test number `4000 0000 0000 0341` simulates, per the [Stripe Testing page](https://stripe.com/docs/testing), a situation where "Attaching this card to a Customer object succeeds, but attempts to charge the customer fail." In my case, I want to treat this situation like an error and send it to the error handler rather than report to the customer that the charge succeeded.

I'm doing this in PHP, so I'm not getting the JSON object from the API but rather a PHP object for the customer. I'm new to the Stripe API so I don't know what else I should be doing here. I tried searching for info about this situation and couldn't find anything helpful. And it doesn't look like this case was handled by existing SO questions.

The excerpt from the code is below. I need to set `$charge_failed` to `true` if the customer was not charged.

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
// Create a customer.
try {
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array( "source" => $my_token, 'email' => $customers_email, "description" => $my_description ));

    $charge_failed = false;  //TODO Set this boolean according to whether the charge passed or failed.

    if ($charge_failed) {
      //TODO Report to the user that the charge failed and they need to resubmit.
      die();
    }
}
catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    // Card was declined. Report the card declined to the user.
    die();
}
catch (\Stripe\Error\RateLimit $e) {
    // Report the error appropriately.
    die();
} catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
    // Report the error appropriately.
    die();
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Authentication $e) {
    // Report the error appropriately.
    die();
} catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
    // Report the error appropriately.
    die();
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
    // Report the error appropriately.
    die();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Report the error appropriately.
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before some days I implemented stripe successfully. Check below hope this will help.

```
if ($params['testmode'] == "on") {
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($params['private_test_key']);
    $pubkey = $params['public_test_key'];
} else {
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($params['private_live_key']);
    $pubkey = $params['public_live_key'];
}

include_once 'Stripe/init.php';
include_once 'Stripe/lib/Stripe.php';

//Set Stripe keys
$params = array(
    "testmode" => "off",
    "private_live_key" => "sk_live_",
    "public_live_key" => "pk_live_",
    "private_test_key" => "sk_test_",
    "public_test_key" => "pk_test_"
);

if ($params['testmode'] == "on") {
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($params['private_test_key']);
    $pubkey = $params['public_test_key'];
} else {
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($params['private_live_key']);
    $pubkey = $params['public_live_key'];
}

if (isset($_POST['stripeToken'])) {
    try {

        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                    'email' => $varUserEmail,
                    'source' => $_POST['stripeToken']
                ));

        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                    'customer' => $customer->id,
                    'amount' => $price,
                    'currency' => 'usd',
                    'description' => $description,
                ));

        $result = "success";
        //Save information in the database and send an email with status
          //Ends here
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        $result = "declined";
         //Save information in the database and send an email with status
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I believe that this situation occurs only if you already have an existing customer object and you are attempting to update their payment method. Your token you are using to create a customer will be invalid prior to attempting the customer creation and customer creation will fail. If this is an initial charge, the javascript method will return a failure.